# Unable to join users table to the other tables using query?

Tags: 7, database

For Drupal 7,
**Field abc and field def** both belong to same content type

```
$query = db_select('field_data_field_abc','ex')
  ->fields('ex', array('field_abc_value'));
$query->join('field_data_field_def', 'fsr', 'fsr.entity_id = ex.entity_id');
$query->addField('fsr', 'field_ort_target_id');
$query->join('node', 'n', 'ex.entity_id = n.nid');     
$query->addField('n','changed');
$query->addField('n', 'uid');
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll() ;
```

In the above query how can I get the user uid and user name using relation between node uid and user uid.
Bcoz. when I joined the users table , my results are empty

Comment: You can use `(string) $query` before execution to see the SQL that's being produced, that should help you identify what needs to be fixed

Comment: Have you tried to view the query executed using the "dpq" function of the [devel module](https://drupal.org/project/devel%E2%80%8E)? Also posting the code/query for which you are getting this problme will help.

Comment: Usually there is an error message in server's error.log during WSODs. Please post it here.

Comment: sorry but I dont get wsod but get a empty result when check the value of $result.